# How to track seperate sessions initiated by the same user/browser

Tags: session, browser, cookies

I have a web application which a user can enter from a number of different pages and follow a number of different paths through the application. I want to be able to add a back to start button to each page which the user can click to take them back to the page they entered the application at.

Currently the user is authenticated by cookie, so I can see what page the cookie is generated on store this and use the link for the back button. However, it is common for a user to open multiple tabs with the application in and enter through multiple entry pages and I want each tab to be able to direct the user back to the correct entry page.

I.e. the user enter the application at page 1 then browses to page 2 - the back button should link to page 1

The user then open another tab at page 3 and browses to page 4 - the back button here should link to page 3.

At this point if the user goes back to tab 1 and browses to page 5 the back button should still link to page 1 here and the back button in the other browser should link to page 3.

The only way I can think of to do this is store the session ID in the get/post request and pass it on every page - can anyone else think of an easier or more elegant solution?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` 
Problem: if he is redirected from google...
Plus:you can hardcode a function that checks the domain :-)